# Shutting down computer for night?

Tags: scripting, startup, shutdown

How can I make a script to shut down computer while I sleep? I mean, it should shut down the computer when I run the script and start the computer at 6.45 am.

Comment: What type of "computer"?

Comment: Relevant question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83685/scheduling-startup-and-shutdown).

Answer (score 5):

Shutdown is pretty easy:

```
echo 'sudo /sbin/shutdown now' | at 11pm
```

Wake-up is much harder - Wake On Lan is the topic to google.

Comment: Very good.  One simplification is that `shutdown` takes a time argument.  To shutdown at 11pm, it is sufficient to run: `sudo /sbin/shutdown 23:00` (23:00 is military time for 11pm).   The use of `at` is unnecessary.

Comment: Quite right @John1024. Edited the answer to use 'now' but you can indeed use shutdown with a date and then cancel it later with `sudo shutdown -c` if necessary.

Comment: Many firmware setups have an option to set a power on time. Using this is easier than Wake On LAN, which would need another device that is always on.